# Formula for combinations not working?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to calculate the number of ways we can arrange the letters U,U,R. When I do this by hand the result is : 3 (UUP , UPU , PUU). But when I apply the formula which gives the number of ways to distribute k indistinguishable objects to n distinguishable boxes it doesn't work. The formula is C(n+k-1,k). To solve it using the formula I do n=3 because we have 3 spaces for the letters and k=2 because it only matters how we can arrange the Us. But the formula then is C(2+3-1,2)=C(4,2)=6 which is double the ways. Am I wrong somewhere?

PS. when I try the formula for 1 distinct object in 3 distinguishable boxes , I get the correct number 3. Why aren't the two things the same? 2 indistinguishable in 3 distinguishable the same as 1 distinguishable in 3 distinguishable

Comment: You aren't distributing indistinguishable objects to distinguishable boxes here.  Here, only two of the three are indistinguishable, the other is distinct, and you are requiring that exactly one goes into each box.

Comment: @lulu the distinct object doesn't matter. It will go where the indistinguishable object are not

Comment: Not following.  The Stars and Bars formula you are using computes the number of ordered $3-$tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $2$.  The six triples are $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)$.  In what way does that connect up to your problem?

Comment: If you think these are the same problem, take the six triples I listed and tell me how each of them corresponds to a different arrangement of $U,U,P$.

Comment: Once again:  in your situation you are requiring that each box end up with exactly one object.  Stars and Bars certainly does not require that.

Comment: the formula you must use is: $3!/2!=3$

Comment: @lulu Thank you I understand now , I thought the formula was that each box could take only one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for finding this is $$\frac{3!}{2!1!}=3$$or more generally $$\frac{n!}{k_1!\times\cdots\times k_m!}$$where $k_1+\cdots+k_m=n$.

This if there are $m$ distinct letters and letter labeled $i$ appears $k_i$ times and the arrangement counts $n$ letters in total.